# How to integrate payment processing platform for peer to peer payment in flutter

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, p2p, onlinebanking

I am new to flutter. I am looking to integrate a peer to peer to transfer money between accounts.

I want flutter to interact with gpay to perform a peer-to-peer payment, meaning a payment between the user and another user in his/her google contacts.

For example, a money transfer from the user to his grandpa, my app just being the UI and acting as a place where the user enters his/her information and which acc he/she is sending the money to, the information is passed to the API(tool for the transfer) and the rest is done by the API itself.

but all the tutorials i see are to 'accept' money from the user https://morioh.com/p/f90ff894ca81 
https://medium.com/swlh/accept-payments-using-google-pay-through-stripe-in-flutter-d65dfaa0091a

Hopefully you understood what I want,
Thankyou

**EDIT:**
Any plugin would do, even if it isn't related to gpay. But it should be universal and should work with any bank provider. The core reason is to build a voice based payment platform

Comment: The use case you are describing isn't supported with the Google Pay APIs. A peer-to-peer payment initiated from the Google Pay app itself.

Comment: is there any other way i can perform perr to per payment other than gpay?

Comment: A lot of that would depend on the country you are in. I'm not familiar with all payment apps, but I suspect many of them will also require you to use their app. I'm not aware of any providing public APIs.

Comment: Even PayPal would do! just anything i can use to make a peer to peer payment platform in flutter

Comment: I believe you can use stripe to receive and send (Transfer API) payment. But there are limitations and of course, they charge you a % for the transaction as a transaction fee.

Comment: but i dont want to recieve or send, instead i want a peer to peer transfer

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/setup

Comment: @Hisham the docs show HOW TO accept payments, but i want to perform peer to peer payment

Comment: Please explain your idea of "peer to peer". If you think you can make transfers of money on their accounts (paypal, google pay, bank) on behalf of them, this is not possible, if it were possible, it's a security risk, for example you could make an app which transfers peoples money to your account. Of course, you could have a form of currency in your app which you can transfer, but you might have to deal with legal issues, its quite a complex procedure. Hence, paypal is a public company. Finance is a heavily regulated industry.

Comment: by peer to peer i mean a payment between the user and another user

Comment: @Joel seems like you are building your own google pay am I right ?

Comment: @Nishutan S yes i am trying to build a voice based payment platform

Comment: Did you solve your problem. If yes, can you please share your experience. I also looking a solution for the same problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the problem yet using voice... but if you are looking for a simple google pay transfer, google has announced official support https://pub.dev/packages/pay and https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/05/google-pay-introduces-flutter-plugin-for-payments.html . I haven't found many tutorials on youtube since it is a very new thing. But you can always reffer to docs